# Mongoose - How to require two Schema files from eachother without circular dependency error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my Node.js project, I have two schemas, `ProductSchema` and `ReviewSchema`. They are located in different files. In `Product.js` (which contains the `ProductSchema`), I have a `.pre remove` hook, that removes all the reviews associated with the product. For this to work, I have to require Review.js (which contains the ReviewSchema). So far so good, but I wanted to implement a hook in the `ReviewSchema` to fire a review's been created/edited/deleted to update the `product's avarageRating field`. For this, I referenced `Review.js`, thus creating a circular dependency error between `Review.js` and `Product.js`.

// Product.js

```
const Review = require("./Review");
    
[...]

ProductSchema.pre("remove", function (next) {
    // ...remove all Reviews that reference it ...
    Review.deleteMany({ product: this._id });
    next();
});

module.exports = new mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
```

// Review.js

```
const Product = require("./Product");

[...]

ReviewSchema.post("save", async function () {
  const reviewsAboutProduct = await Review.find({ product: this.product });

  const total = reviewsAboutProduct.reduce((prevValue, review) => {
    return prevValue + review.rating;
  }, 0);

  const averageRating = total / reviewsAboutProduct.length;
  console.log(total, averageRating);
// below is the line referenced in the response error message
  const product = Product.findOne({_id: product}); 
  product.averageRating = averageRating;
  product.save();
});

const Review = mongoose.model("Review", ReviewSchema);
module.exports = Review;
```

I think because of this circular dependency, I get the following error:

```
(node:8696) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
```

And in the response:

```
<pre>ReferenceError: Cannot access &#39;product&#39; before initialization<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at model.&lt;anonymous&gt; (\models\Review.js:47:42)
```

What should I do? Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Have a look at this. https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3826#issuecomment-1024873841.
Best option would be to use a dependency injection container.

Comment: Thank you for the help, this indeed solved it! @vicki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This solution](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3826#issuecomment-1024873841) suggested by vicki helped me to solve this problem.

Review.js file:

```
const Review = mongoose.model("Review", ReviewSchema);
module.exports = Review;
const Product = require("./Product");
```

Product.js file:

```
module.exports = new mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
const Review = require("./Review");
```